# How do I get pyinstaller to not generate those extra folders

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

When I'm calling --onefile on my pyinstaller to get a file into an exe, I don't want to have to delete all these useless folders and files after I got the exe I wanted. Is there a way to tell it to not make these folders?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. It needs all those folder and stuff to package the executable. You'll either have to suck it up or make a script that deletes them for you.

Edit: I haven't used pyinstaller, but I do have experience with python and compiled languages, so I would guess that packaging a non-compiled language like python would need a lot of "junk" files. Also, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try -F to create a one-file bundled executable.